# Optimisation not working with inline scripts

Tags: asp.net, optimization

I shifted all my page inline scripts to .js files. I have installed the optimisation package from nuget and have setup my css and javascript bundles.

Everything is working fine, until i set `EnableOptimisation = true`. That's when i start to see random errors in firebug console.

I tried going through all my inline scripts and cannot seem to see any issues with it.

For example, this is the login screen and these are the errors i am getting in the console:

[image: Console Errors]

**This is the button where the `ValidateLogin` is called on client click:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
     ID="cmdLogin" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Text="Login"
     OnClick="cmdLogin_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateLogin();">
     <span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in"></i></span>&nbsp Login
</asp:LinkButton>
```

**This is the .js file where the `ValidateLogin` function is defined:**

```
var results;
function ValidateLogin() {
    results = 0;

    var username = $('[data-input=username]').val();
    var password = $('[data-input=password]').val();


    checkEmpty(password, 'Password cannot be blank!');
    checkEmpty(username, 'Username cannot be blank!');

    if (results > 0) { return false; }
}
```

**This is the part in the Login page where i reference the scripts:**

```
<%:Scripts.Render("~/Script/core") %>
<%:Scripts.Render("~/Script/displayModal") %>
<%:Scripts.Render("~/Script/clientValidation") %>
<%:Scripts.Render("~/Script/loginValidation") %>
<%:Scripts.Render("~/Script/enquiryValidation") %>
<%:Scripts.Render("~/Script/loginSetup") %>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Show us the relevant bits of code and the errors please

Comment: @PedroG.Dias i have edited the question